# Get the value of data atribute and store in array with jquery and store in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

It is possible to count the elements within a div and store them in an array.

I created the element data-head-ref to know to which group they belong to the internal elements.
Example: **data-head-ref='region'** contains the realtional elemento to **region**

As dynamically create and populate an array similar to the structure below.
How to get the number and value who belongs with jquery.

Is this possible?

```
var headerBlockElements = {
   'region':  {
      'numberItems': 3, // the inside child elements
      'nameItems':  {
         “North”, “South”, “Center”
       }
   },

   'brands': {
      'numberItems': 2,
      'nameItems': {
         “Food”, “Autos”
      }
   }
}
```

I have the following example [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gonzalo2683/5fo380mw/)

```
<div class='column-header clearfix' data-head-ref='region'>
    <div class='header-inner'><span class='header-inner-title-dos'>Region</span></div>

    <div class='level-two' data-head='Nort'><span class='title'>Nort</span>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='EEUU'><span class='title'>EEUU</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Canada'><span class='title'>Canada</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Mexico'><span class='title'>Mexico</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='level-two' data-head='Sout'><span class='title'>Sout</span>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Venezuela'><span class='title'>Venezuela</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Ecuador'><span class='title'>Ecuador</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Argentina'><span class='title'>Argentina</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Colombia'><span class='title'>Colombia</span></div>   
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Uruguay'><span class='title'>Uruguay</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='level-two' data-head='Center'><span class='title'>Center</span>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Panama'><span class='title'>Panama</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Guatemala'><span class='title'>Guatemala</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Honduras'><span class='title'>Honduras</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Costa Rica'><span class='title'>Costa Rica</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='column-header clearfix' data-head-ref='Brands'>
    <div class='header-inner'><span class='header-inner-title-dos'>Brands</span></div>

    <div class='level-two' data-head='Food'><span class='title'>Food</span>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Pizza Hut'><span class='title'>Pizza Hut</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Burger King'><span class='title'>Burger King</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Taco Bell'><span class='title'>Taco Bell</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='level-two' data-head='Autos'><span class='title'>Autos</span>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Toyota'><span class='title'>Toyota</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Mazda'><span class='title'>Mazda</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Volvo'><span class='title'>Volvo</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='Chevrolet'><span class='title'>Chevrolet</span></div>
        <div class='level-three' data-option='BMW'><span class='title'>BMW</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. I'm a bit shaky on what exactly you want to grab but here's something that should help.

### PRE JQuery 1.6

```
var customArray =[];
$('[data-head-ref]').each(function(){
     var Items = ""; 
     $("[data-head]", this).each(function(){
        if(Items.length!=0){Items +=",";}
        Items +=$(this).attr("data-head");
     });

     customArray[$(this).attr('data-head-ref')] =  {
             'numberItems': $("[data-head]", this).length, 
             'nameItems': Items}; 
});
```

### JQuery 1.6 +

```
var customArray =[];
$('[data-head-ref]').each(function(){
     var Items = ""; 
     $("[data-head]", this).each(function(){
        if(Items.length!=0){Items +=",";}
        Items +=$(this).prop("data-head");
     });

     customArray[$(this).prop('data-head-ref')] =  {
             'numberItems': $("[data-head]", this).length, 
             'nameItems': Items}; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, there is only one correction, the method of -**lenth** has syntax error. The length inside of the second each function has the error.

Comment: Oh good catch on the typo. I'll update my answer. If this solved your problem please mark it as the correct answer. And if you found it helpful upvotes are always welcome.